# How to implement an interactive tone curve in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, processing, curve

I want to implement a photo editor in python using flask. So far, I managed to apply an s curve to a photo, like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('apple.jpg')

def sToneCurve(frame):
    look_up_table = np.zeros((256, 1), dtype='uint8')
    for i in range(256):
        look_up_table[i][0] = 255 * (np.sin(np.pi * (i / 255 - 1 / 2)) + 1) / 2
    return cv2.LUT(frame, look_up_table)

image_contrasted = sToneCurve(image)

cv2.imwrite('apple_dark.jpg', image_contrasted)
```

How could I implement an interactive tone curve, so that the user could select how he would like to edit the photos, like this: [tone curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2J9P.png) and not be a predefined formula applied to the photo, as in the code above. What would be the best approach, what libraries and visualizations for the curve plots to use?

Answer (score 1):

You implement this using "standard" polynomial fitting: you have N points that you need a curve through, so you find the N-1<sup>st</sup> order polynomial that does that, then use that polynomial as your mapping function.

You're already using `numpy`, so use [numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) with:

- `x` all your points' x coordinates, including your black and white points (which in a proper tone curve users should be able to move off of (0,0) and (1,1) respective),
- `y` all your points' y coordinates,
- `deg` if the polynomial has to pass through all points, which it should, this should be equal to `len(x) - 1`, as two points is a line, or a first degree polynomial, three points is a quadratic curve, or a second degree polynomial, etc. "The" polynomial through N points is an N-1 degree polynomial,
- the rest of the args shouldn't particularly matter.

This gives you a numpy array of polynomial coefficients (let's call that array `c`) that you can then use for mapping: any pixel with lightness/intensity value `i` should get mapped to:

```
mapped = f(I) = c[0] * i**0 + c[1] * i**1 + c[2] * i**2 + ...
```

Which thankfully numpy can do for you by simply using the corresponding [polyval](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html) function.

And of course, to make that fast, what you really want to do is build a LUT that you can just directly consult, every time the user changes a coordinate in the tone curve UI, so:

```py
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit, polyval

# How big of a LUT you actually need depends entirely
# on the bit depth you're working with, of course...
BIT_DEPTH = 2**16
TONE_LUT = range(0, BIT_DEPTH)

def update_from_tone_ui(coordinates):
  """
  Called on user value update, with coordinates being
  a list-of-lists a la [[0,0], [0.1,0.1], ...]
  """
  x, y = zip(*coordinates)
  coefficients = polyfit(x, y, len(x) - 1)
  f = lamba i: clamp(polyval(i, coefficients), 0, 1)

  # And remember to make sure the input range to f() matches
  # the actual x/y domain that we used for the polyfit:
  divisor = BIT_DEPTH - 1
  TONE_LUT = [BIT_DEPTH * f(i/divisor) for i in range(0, BIT_DEPTH)]
```

with `clamp` coming from "somewhere", but if you don't already have one then it's trivially implemented with some shortcut returns:

```py
def clamp(n, floor, ceiling):
  if n < floor: return floor
  if n > ceiling: return ceiling
  return n
```

(And of course make sure to adjust your clamping values if you don't want your tone curve x and y coordinates in [0,1])

Now, rather than running the mapping function every time, you just directly look up the mapped value. Note that you get a bit of freedom in terms of precision: you could use a tone curve in which the x and y values run from 0 to 1, or you use have them run from 0 to whatever-bit-depth-you-use (2<sup>8</sup>, 2<sup>16</sup>, what have you) but whatever you use, make sure you scale your actual pixel intensities accordingly when you generate your LUT. Otherwise things will look *really* interesting.